# Why do eggs lack an endoplasmic reticulum?

Tags: cell-biology

Trueman's Elementary Biology book I found says that the endoplasmic reticulum is absent in eggs, but no reason is given. Why is it absent?

Comment: I did not know there was no endoplasmic reticulum in the eggs. Can you please add a reference we could easily check up?

Comment: I just found in my book. It might had initially but i thing it is reduced later .But I will try to add a reference

Comment: I think there is some mistake, check [this] (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012160699994459). It shows eggs (at least mammalian) have ER

Comment: In addition, these Calcium waves produces by ER stores are way to block another sperm entry into egg.

Comment: I THINK THE BOOK SAID ABOUT CHICKEN EGGS ..

Answer (score 2):

I could find no indication that eggs are lacking an endoplasmic reticulum. On the contrary, I could find papers written on the ER in eggs of several species.

Mouse: [The onset of activation responsiveness during maturation coincides with the formation of the cortical endoplasmic reticulum in oocytes of *Xenopus laevis*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012160684901775)

Sea urchin: [Structural changes of the endoplasmic reticulum of sea urchin eggs during fertilization](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8462752)

Human: [The relationship between pregnancy outcome and smooth endoplasmic reticulum clusters in MII human oocytes](http://m.humrep.oxfordjournals.org/content/19/7/1591.full)

Frogs: [The onset of activation responsiveness during maturation coincides with the formation of the cortical endoplasmic reticulum in oocytes of *Xenopus laevis*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012160684901775)

However, as can be read in the sea urchin paper, the ER changes after fertilization:

> We interpret these observations to indicate that in the first few minutes after fertilization, the egg's ER is fragmented

For other species, I could only find evidence that the ER reorganizes after fertilization because of [changed calcium signaling needs](http://dev.biologists.org/content/130/13/2867.short)